# Why hasFile() method return false?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I send file from my html form and dump my file in controller. Dump result return correct result with file name.

```
dump($request->file);
```

But if I check for true or false then `var_dump()` return false.

```
var_dump($request->hasFile('file'));
```

[image]

Comment: what `dump($request->file('file'))` gives??

Comment: Here is my html code: `<input type="file" name="file" id="file">`

Comment: did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data">` in your form? may be your are missing this

Comment: @Sohel0415 exactly, I also think only string is passed over there.

Comment: Not I forgot add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form! Maybe it is a my generaly problem. @Sohel0415

Comment: add your view code and try `dump($request->file('file'))` and see what it gives

Comment: Now All working if I add enctype

Comment: that's good, congrats :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$request->file` is a string and not instance of [`Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files).

You should use `->hasFile()` only with files.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding another thing.
When you don't add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside your form then you will get also this types of problem.

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Or using form helper `'file' => true`,

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['store'], 'file' => true]) !!}
```

I think this will help someone.